# Kriging(Gaussian Process Regression) Error too high and no plot visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, geospatial, gaussian-process

I'm almost done with my Spatial Interpolation, however the result plot isn't what I would like to have.
I followed the documentation of scikit-gstools about kriging: https://scikit-gstat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/01_getting_started.html

the last plot is what I want to have.

my current code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pprint import pprint
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from skgstat import Variogram, OrdinaryKriging

data = pd.read_csv("kerpencsv.csv")
print("Loaded %d rows and %d columns" % data.shape)
data.head()
data = pd.read_csv("kerpencsv.csv")
print("Loaded %d rows and %d columns" % data.shape)
data.head()
```

OUT: Loaded 1046 rows and 3 columns

longitude   latitude    subsidence

0   6.702397    50.91644    -6.317195

1   6.703119    50.91653    -5.610300

2   6.703386    50.91633    -4.985516

3   6.702680    50.91618    -5.956828

4   6.703945    50.91625    -4.455712

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 9))
art = ax.scatter(data.longitude,data.latitude, s=50, c=data.subsidence, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(art);

V = Variogram(data[['longitude', 'latitude']].values, data.subsidence, normalize=False, maxlag=5, n_lags=15)

fig = V.plot(show=False)
print('Sample variance: %.2f   Variogram sill: %.2f' % (data.subsidence.var(), V.describe()['sill']))
pprint(V.describe())
print(V)
print(V)
spherical Variogram
-------------------
Estimator:         matheron
Effective Range:   0.05
Sill:              222.34
Nugget:            0.00
        

ok = OrdinaryKriging(V, min_points=5, max_points=15, mode='exact')

xx, yy = np.mgrid[6.67:6.69:6.72j, 50.86:50.88:50.92j]
field = ok.transform(xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()).reshape(xx.shape)
s2 = ok.sigma.reshape(xx.shape)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))

art = axes[0].matshow(field.T, origin='lower', cmap='plasma')
axes[0].set_title('Interpolation')
axes[0].plot(data.longitude, data.latitude, '+k')
axes[0].set_xlim((6.67,6.72))
axes[0].set_ylim((50.86,50.92))
plt.colorbar(art, ax=axes[0])
art = axes[1].matshow(s2.T, origin='lower', cmap='YlGn_r')
axes[1].set_title('Kriging Error')
plt.colorbar(art, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].plot(data.longitude, data.latitude, '+w')
axes[1].set_xlim((6.67,6.72))
axes[1].set_ylim((50.86,50.92));
```

[output of krigng model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruZVR.png)

as you can see I don't get a colored kriging model and a plot which reflects a very high kriging error.
I'm unsure how to deal with this, and I'd be greatful for any help!